# Independent Sound Generative Factors

Tags: audio, sound

I am currently in the process of exploring independent sound-generating factors (e.g., Timbre, Pitch, Amplitude, Spacialization, Effects, Instrumentation, etc.) and I'm totally new to this enterprise of digital sound processing. My current pursuit led me to this forum and I would appreciate answers on some independent factors that can be used to generate simple sounds if that's even possible. If, possible what sound synthesizers can you recommend to do the job of synthetic sound generation. If this process can be automated (programmed), that would be super.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.